# how to add multiple line breaks conveniently in shiny?

Tags: html, r, shiny, line-breaks

I want put multiple line breaks in my shiny app.
Instead of

```
br(),
br(),
br(),
...
```

is there a more convenient way of doing it?

Comment: The easiest way would be to modify your css https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703601/how-to-give-line-break-from-css-without-using-br

Comment: Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340847/control-the-height-in-fluidrow-in-r-shiny

Comment: Seems pretty convenient to me - only 5 characters and stays in the Shiny idiom (no javascript). What kind of convenience are you looking for?

Comment: @MikeWise Like 10 lines of breaks......putting 10 lines of `br(),` doesn't really cost too much, but that's not what programming does...is it? Programming is supposed to do these repetitive things as I understand...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have no idea if that's convenient for you, but it saves you some typing.

`linebreaks(n)` repeats `<br/>` n times and parses it as HTML.

```
library(shiny)


linebreaks <- function(n){HTML(strrep(br(), n))}

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel(
              p( 
                  h1("first sentence", align = "center"),

                  linebreaks(10),

                  h3("second sentence", align = "center")
                )
              )
  )
```

Comment: I'm defining the function. ```linebreaks <- function(n){HTML(strrep(br(), n))}```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62072701/9096420) is definitely better for larger amount of breaks, but if it isn't clear, you don't have to put a break in between `br()` in your editor (they can all go on the same line; RE the OP comment: *"10 lines of breaks......putting 10 lines of `br()`"*):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel(
              p( 
                  h1("first sentence", align = "center"),

                  br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),br(),

                  h3("second sentence", align = "center")
                )
              )
  )
```

Not as pretty as the function in the accepted answer, but it is actually fewer characters in this particular case.